# Copy directory contents with Ansible (without replace destination files)

Tags: ansible, copy

There is a directory under `/var/test1` with content:

```
.
..
.git
.gitignore
file1
file2
```

and I want to copy it on an other location `/var/test2` with pre-existing content:

```
.
..
file1
```

If I use the Ansible `copy`:

```
- copy:
  # note the trailing `/` at `src: /var/test1/` in order to copy the contents
  src: /var/test1/
  dest: /var/test2
```

it will replace the `file1` in the `/var/test2`

How can I copy the directory contents without replacing the files at the destination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by default ansible forces overwrites, maybe disabling it would help your case (force=no).

Comment: Why I never saw with option before? lol so dam obvious: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use [synchronize_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html). It has `delete` option:

> Delete files in dest that don't exist (after transfer, not before) in the src path. This option requires recursive=yes.

```
- synchronize:
   src: /var/test1
   dest: /var/test2
   recursive: True
   delete: False
```

Comment: Does not answer the question but is exactly what I was looking for!